# wordpress running from a subfolder not working on live page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've just got my first domain. I have created a wordpress blog on my wamp server with wordpress data in subfolder now on my local pc everything works fine.  This however is not the case on uk2 hosted domain.  Best I seem to be able to do is get the basic wording for the homepage to load no theme so nothing loogs correct etc. Other pages do load sort of but with no formatting again.    If I try and go to wp-admin i get **Not Found, Error 404**.

I have been through every post i can find to try and track down issue.  Spent the last 2 days on.  You guys and girls are my last hope :).  Here is list of what I've already checked already(That i can remember):-

1. changin the siteurl and home settings with or without the subfolder added
2. Checked permissions including if there is another .htaccess file causing the issue
3. tried changing the .Htaccess as per other peoples suggest to add folder name to  RewriteRule . /index.php [L] line & 
   RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
4. manually removed data in the permalink_structure field
5. renamed plugin folder to see if a plugin was the issue
6. cleared cache and cookies
7. Manually changed the theme to default similar outcome

**my . htaccess is as follows**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**i have a index.php as follows**

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/web/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

**I've also updated my wp_options table I've modified both**

```
siteurl     http://example.com
home    http://example.com/web/
```

As well as making sure that wp-config.php has all the same database names and logins.

PS if blat everything and just install the default 2017 theme using uk2 wordpress installer into a sub folder. it looks just like black wordpress site everything working fine.

Comment: I don't know how but my website is now working when i put both site url and home to point to right places it now, works.  

Perhaps someone could tell me how i loose those.  The main reason for putting wordpress into a subfolder is to make less easy to hack that's pointless if every page on the site has subfolder name in it.  as I sated earlier ive tried a lot of things.  I'm guessing there might be a combination i've missed

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory